# How to get records where values in different columns are duplicated?

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

I have a table made up of player id, team id, year and order. The same player can belong to multiple teams in one year, but order must be different.

Table is as follows:

| player | team | year | order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 2020 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 2021 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2020 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 2020 | 0 |

In above table, row 4 and 5 have the same value in order column for the same player id and same year. This is wrong.

Rows 2 and 3 would be positive example, where the same player have moved to a new team in the same year, but at the same time, the order value is different.

How can I get a list of results with the records with problems? In above table it would be rows 4 and 5.

I am struggling to get a SQL query that works... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tip - avoid using reserved keywords such as `order` otherwise you have to delimit their usage everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select those records that are duplicate, and filter them:

```
select * 
from mytable
WHERE (`player`,`year`,`order`) in (SELECT `player`,`year`, `order`
                                    FROM mytable
                                    GROUP BY `player`,`year`, `order`
                                    HAVING count(*)>1);
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/5mstecIC)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way would be to filter using a windowed count:

```
select *
from (
  select *, Count(*) over(partition by player, year, `order`) cnt
  from t
)t
where cnt > 1;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EoLy6LXy)